# Image view cropped to certain shape

Tags: java, android, xml, image, android-drawable

I am creating a form of social media app in which i will be loading in images into android studios from a web hosting server and displaying them in an imageview I want to crop the images to a specific [Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuQoX.png), how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and an image transformation library like [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)